# What is to be expected in terms of wifi range with line of sight?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have tried to look this up but i cannot find where to start, I imagine this is very transmitter specific based off of power and the like, so if someone could explain *how* to calculate this i would greatly appreciate it, but assume we are talking about the D-Link DWA-127 which is marketed as a "high gain" antenna.

As far as i understand it, most omni-directional wifi antennas transmit in a torus-shape based off of the orientation of the antennas, for this assume both antennas are in the same orientation, standing 90 degrees up perpendicular to the ground. Is there a way i could calculate the maximum distance these two antenna can connect whilst maintaining a line of sight?

For what its worth, the application I am using this for is to transmit between a drone in the air and a phone on the ground. I would like to know the max range the drone can fly directly upwards before connection would be lost. Is there a type of antenna that can fire a directed, conical signal straight down that would be of greater benefit to this application?

Comment: Don't bother: While there are both simple and complex ways of calculating signal strength at a distance, or range, given known antenna and power parameters, in the real world they vary too much to be anything more than a vague indication.

Comment: +1, noise in both wifi bands is so variable that you can't really get any useful figures. DJI etc use 5.8Ghz radios and others (AKA not Wifi) to avoid as much of this as possible. There are legal implications though.